# pyral addcollection is not working for multi value dropdown

Tags: pyral

Not able to addcollection for a multidropdown field, fields are multi value drop down and modifiable = yes.

error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyral/restapi.py", line 1206, 
>       in addCollectionItems
>       target_type = target._type
>       AttributeError: 'RallyRESTResponse' object has no attribute '_type'

Code:

```
c_VerifiedinEnvironment = [{'_ref': '/AllowedAttributeValue/Dev01'}]
defect = rally.get('Defect','DE47147')
rally.addCollectionItems(defect, c_VerifiedinEnvironment)
```

New to Rally! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The version 1.4.1 has a correction related to `addCollectionItems`, as stated in the Release Notes

> 1.4.1 Support for TestFolderStatus attribute in TestFolder. Fixed defect in addCollectionItems

You could try to update (`pip install -U pyral`) to see whether this solves your problem.